# Polymorphic use of templates

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism

Here, the context of polymorphic is expecting 'Derived' from 'Base&.

Given

```
class P { };
class Q : public P { };
auto operator + (const P& p, int x) -> DYNAMIC_DECLTYPE(P) {
    DYNAMIC_DECLTYPE(P) p2(p);
    p2.func(x);
    return p2;
}
```

Is there a way to have DYNAMIC_DECLTYPE working? I want to use this form instead of

```
template <typename T> T operator + (const T& t, int x)
```

or have a potentially long list of

```
if (!strcmp(typeid(p).name(), typeid(derived()).name()) { ... }
```

because the latter cannot be used to restrict T to P or subclasses thereof (prove me wrong, if possible).

Comment: Use the template form and add a `static_assert(std::is_base_of<P, T>::value, "Boo");` to your code. Your code cannot work as it is, since you would at the very least have to convert `p` to its actual type, too.

Comment: `if (typeid(p) == typeid(derived))` is enough. `if (!strcmp(typeid(p).name(), typeid(derived()).name())` not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is in every sense of the word a template pattern: You have an unbounded *family* of return types with matching function argument types. This should simply be a straight template.

If you want to restrict the permissible types, you should add some typetrait magic. Perhaps like this:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<P, T>::value, T>::type
operator+(T const & t, int x)
{
    T s(t);
    s.func(x);
    return s;
}
```

(If `func` returns a reference, you can shortcut this to `return T(t).func(x);`.)

Comment: I believe the return type needs to be 'typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<P, T>::value, T>::type'